# Remove the Read More link if post is very short

Tags: wordpress, post

When showing posts in the home page, if a post is really short (say, shorter than `the_excerpt`) is there a way to find out? That way I would remove the *Read more* link since the entire post is already being displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple get the excerpt and post word/char length.
Suppose

```
if ($post_l > $excerpt_l)
{
//show read more
}
else
{
//shoe post without read more
}
```

PHP word count

```
function count_words($str) 
{
$no = count(explode(" ",$str));
return $no;
}
```